# ¿Como puedo llamar a un video almacenado en MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose, multer

Hola estoy desarrollando un proyecto de subida de videos y tengo un problema al llamarlo en el Front-End, solo me aparece el nombre que esta designado y no me aparece el video que subo, aca esta el codigo Back-End para almacenar el video en si:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: path.join(__dirname, 'public/img/upload'),
    filename: (req, file, cb, filename) => {
        console.log(file);
        cb(null, uuid() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
}) 
app.use(multer({storage}).single('video'));
```

eso es donde inicio multer y asignarle un nombre random y el lugar donde va a estar almacenado el video.

```
router.post('/taller/uploadModulo', async (req, res) => {
  const modulo           = new Modulo();
  modulo.nombre          = req.body.nombre;
  modulo.contenidos      = req.body.contenidos;
  modulo.calendarizacion = req.body.calendarizacion;
  modulo.evaluacion      = req.body.evaluacion;
  modulo.duracion        = req.body.duracion;
  modulo.material        = req.body.material;
  modulo.num_modulo      = req.body.num_modulo;
  modulo.nombretaller    = req.body.nombretaller;

  modulo.filename        = req.file.filename;
  modulo.path            = '../public/img/upload/' + req.file.filename;
  modulo.originalname    = req.file.originalname;
  modulo.mimetype        = req.file.mimetype;
  modulo.size            = req.file.size;

  await modulo.save();
  console.log(modulo.size);
  res.redirect('/taller/modulo');
});

router.get('/taller/modulo', async (req, res) => {
  const modulos = await Modulo.find();
  res.render('./verTaller', { modulos });
});

router.get('/taller/modulo/:id', async (req, res) =>{
  const { id } = req.params;
  const modulo = await Modulo.findById(id);
  res.render('./taller/verVideo', { modulo });
});
```

este es el codigo de almacenamiento del video y para poder llamarlo en el Front-End con una funcion
                        `<% modulos.forEach(function(modulo)) {} %>`

además de asignarle un id para poder borrar el video posteriormente, este es el codigo Front-End donde llamo al video con la funcion forEach:

```
       <% modulos.forEach(function (modulo) { %>

        <div class="card animated fadeInDown">
            <video src="<%= modulo.path %>" class="card-img-top" alt="<%= modulo.filename %>"></video>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title"><%= modulo.nombre %></h5>
                <p><%= format(modulo.created_at) %></p>
                <a href="/taller/modulo/<%= modulo._id %>" class="btn btn-primary">
                   View 
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <% }) %>
```

Comment: ¿logras subir el video?

Comment: Sip, logro subir el video, pero al llamarlo con la etiqueta del video, no aparece nada

Comment: ¿Has configurado correctamente [`express.static()`](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html#serving-static-files-in-express)?

Answer (score 0):

yo utilizo esta función para retornar archivos desde el back:

```
function getImageFile(req, res) {
    var imageFile = req.params.imageFile
    var path_file = './uploads/campaign/' + imageFile
    fs.exists(path_file, function (exists) {
        if (exists) {
            res.sendFile(path.resolve(path_file))
        } else {
            res.status(200).send({ message: 'no existe la imagen' })
        }
    })
}
```

para el front :

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {
  Card, CardImg, CardText, CardBody,
  CardTitle, CardSubtitle, Button, Container,
  Row,Col
} from 'reactstrap';

import IndexNavbar from "components/Navbars/IndexNavbar.js";
import ListCampaignsHeader from "components/Headers/ListCampaignsHeader.js";
import TransparentFooter from "components/Footers/TransparentFooter.js";
import WebpayPlusController from 'components/TBK/src/controllers/WebpayNormalController.js'


function Donate (){
  console.log('donar')
  WebpayPlusController.init()
}

export default class listCampaigns extends React.Component {
  state = {
    campaigns: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
    axios.get('TU API')
      .then(res => {
        const campaigns = res.data;
        this.setState({ campaigns });
      })
  }

      render() {
        return (
          <>
            <IndexNavbar />
            <ListCampaignsHeader />
            <Container className="text-center">
              <Row className="justify-content-md-center">
                <Col lg="8" md="12">
                  <h1 className="title">Lista de Iniciativas</h1>
                  <h5 className="description">
                    Acá podrás encontrar campañas de todo tipo para ayudar.
                    Recuerda que Tú puedes hacer la diferencia.
                  </h5>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </Container>
            <Container>
              {this.state.campaigns.map(campaign =>
                <Card key={campaign._id} style={{ width: "60rem" }}>
                   <CardImg src={campaign.image} alt="Card image cap" />
                  <CardBody>
                    <CardTitle>{campaign.name}</CardTitle>
                    <CardSubtitle>{campaign.date}</CardSubtitle>
                    <CardText>{campaign.description}</CardText>
                    <Button>Detalles</Button>
                    <Button onClick={Donate} >Donar</Button>
                  </CardBody>
                </Card>
              )
              }
            </Container>
            <TransparentFooter />
          </>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: ¿De qué manera el código del front en [React](https://es.reactjs.org) de tu respuesta se relaciona con el código del front en [EJS](https://ejs.co) de la pregunta? Si bien tu código puede funcionar, no es una respuesta a la duda planteada por el OP. Debemos procurar ser consistentes con las respuestas. Te invito a leer [answer]. Saludos